# How to Loop through by Models in View page and bind data in controls for Save and Update feature?

Tags: razor

I have two models, as follows below. Getting problem in View,

1. RelationType: holds data like “Mother, Father, Primary Teacher,
   Legal Guardian...etc.”
2. Parents: holds personal profile information about Mother or Father
       or Primary Teacher...etc. of a children.

In RelationType Model,

```
public class RelationType
    {
        public int RelationTypeID { get; set; }
        public string RelationName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
    }
```

In Model,

```
public class Parent
    {
        public int ParentID { get; set; }
        [Required,Display(Name="Family")]
        public int FamilyID { get; set; }
        [Required,Display(Name="Relationship")]
        public int RelationTypeID { get; set; }
        [Required, MaxLength(50), Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50), Display(Name = "Middle Name")]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50), Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(12), DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:###-##-####}")]
        public string SSN { get; set; }             
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public virtual Family Families { get; set; }
        public virtual RelationType RelationTypes { get; set; }        

    }
```

In Controller,

```
  public ActionResult Index(int id)
        {
      ViewBag.Parents = db.ParentRepository.GetAllByRefID(p => p.FamilyID == id).ToList();
ViewBag.RelationTypes = db.RelationTypeRepository.GetAll().ToList();
return View();
        }
```

In my View [Index.cshtml] page,

```
@model StudentEnrollmentViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create / Update Childer’s parents information";
    List<Model.Parent> parentsmodel = ViewBag.Parents;
    List<Model.RelationType> relationtypes = ViewBag.RelationTypes;
}

<h2>Student Enrollment</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

  @foreach (var rel in relationtypes)
                {
                    foreach (var itm in parentsmodel)
                    {
                        if (rel.RelationTypeID == itm.RelationTypeID)
                        {                           
                    <h2>@rel.RelationName 's Information</h2>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => itm.ParentID, new { Value = itm.ParentID })
                    <div class="span12">
                        <div class="span3">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => itm.FirstName)
                        </div>
                        <div class="span3">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => itm.MiddleName)
                        </div>
                        <div class="span3">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => itm.LastName)
                        </div>
                        <div class="span3">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => itm.SSN)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span12">
                        <div class="span3">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => itm.FirstName)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => itm.FirstName)
                        </div>
                        <div class="span3">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => itm.MiddleName)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => itm.MiddleName)
                        </div>
                        <div class="span3">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => itm.LastName)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => itm.LastName)
                        </div>
                        <div class="span3">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => itm.SSN)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => itm.SSN)
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="span12">
                        <div class="span4">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => itm.Email)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span12">
                        <div class="span4">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => itm.Email)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => itm.Email)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                           <h4>@rel.RelationName Information not provided!</h4>
                    <div class="span12">
                        <div class="span3">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => itm.FirstName)
                        </div>
                        <div class="span3">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => itm.MiddleName)
                        </div>
                        <div class="span3">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => itm.LastName)
                        </div>
                        <div class="span3">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => itm.SSN)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span12">
                        <div class="span3">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => itm.FirstName)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => itm.FirstName)
                        </div>
                        <div class="span3">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => itm.MiddleName)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => itm.MiddleName)
                        </div>
                        <div class="span3">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => itm.LastName)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => itm.LastName)
                        </div>
                        <div class="span3">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => itm.SSN)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => itm.SSN)
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="span12">
                        <div class="span4">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => itm.Email)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span12">
                        <div class="span4">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => itm.Email)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => itm.Email)
                        </div>
                    </div>

                        }                  
                    }



                }
}
```

My goal is to bind existing parents (mother and father...etc.) information in to the controls then save it into the database if modifies. Existing parents information comes in IF block, if the parents information is not available then have to provide interface for create a new parents (mother / father/  ...) which will comes in ELSE block.

In the above code (View) I am unable to bind parent’s information properly and it should be categorised by relationship like mother, Father, Primary Teacher…etc.  like below

***Father Information Found!***

Name: XXXXXX Last Name: XXXXXX  Middle Name: XXXXXX  SSN: XXXXXX Email : XXXXXX@xyz.com

***Mother Information Not Found!! [Please provide below]***

Name: ***_*_** Last Name: ***_*_** Middle Name: ***_*_** SSN: ***_*_** Email : ***_***

***Primary Teacher Information Found!***

Name: XXXXXX Last Name: XXXXXX  Middle Name: XXXXXX  SSN: XXXXXX Email : XXXXXX@xyz.com

***Legal Guardian Information Not Found!![Please provide below]***

Name: ***_*_** Last Name: ***_*_** Middle Name: ***_*_** SSN: ***_*_** Email : ***_***

***Some other relationship…etc. [Please provide below]***

Name: ***_*_** Last Name: ***_*_** Middle Name:***_*_** SSN: ***_*_** Email : ***_***

***SAVE***

By clicking on SAVE button, provided information above should be create/ update  into the database. I already have code for Create / Update. But my problem in displaying the controls with / without data which should be categorized by relationship types

Could you please help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you do you mean by cannot properly bind information properly? If I understand correctly you are trying to do a lookup for a person and determine whether that person's profile information already has mother/father/teach/etc. info, correct? If so we can fix up the model and get this achieved easily. (naming your model as Parent throws me off a little but perhaps I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. I apologize.)